# Show invisible panel on a click in a command button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, panel

I have a panel which has `visible="false"` and I want to make it visible with a click on the `commandButton`. I've already tried this code below but when I click on the button, the panel shows up and hides at the same time.

```
<h:form>
 <p:panel>
  <p:dataTable ...>
...
      <f:facet name="footer">
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" ajax="false" update="picklist" title="Add Travellers" onclick="hidenpanel.show();"></p:commandButton>
       </f:facet>
  </p:dataTable> 
 </p:panel> 
 <p:panel  id="pickList" widgetVar="hidenpanel" styleClass="pick" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; border: 0;" visible="false" header="Travellers" >
 </p:panel> 
</h:form>
```

When I pressed F12 in the Chrome page I got 2 errors and 1 warning.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/visasMarketing/RES_NOT_FOUND

Failed to load resource http://ads.okitspace.com/uploads/cover.js?id=c1f09f9576240d2f2907b350ed2de188&affid=SOFTPLUS

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `p:remoteCommand`.

The [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
<p:commandButton ... ajax="false" ... />
```

with `ajax="false"` you're effectively firing a synchronous (non-ajax) request which in turn has the default consequence a full page reload. You need to **remove** it so that it defaults to `ajax="true"` which would fire an asynchronous request and thus the page will stay the same.

Comment: BalusC, i think that he wants a button just to show the panel, so...wouldn't be better to set `type = button`? Then there will be no requests, only client side interaction.... This is what i think at least, am i wrong?

Comment: @Pellizon: He's explicitly updating the panel's content before display by `update`. This requires an ajax action. If he didn't had that (or actually didn't need that and was just being ignorant), then `type="button"` would indeed be more appropriate after removing the `update` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC i removed the ajax="false" and the button just reload the page and didn't show up the panel

Comment: The cause of this problem is not visible in the information provided so far. Please edit the question to include an SSCCE along with information about versions used and if the HTTP traffic and JS console are fine.

Comment: How to check if the http traffic and JS console are fine?

Comment: Check browser's builtin web developer toolset. Press F12.